# Return single SELECT row in BEFORE UPDATE trigger

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

From [41.9.1. Triggers on Data Changes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER):

> To alter the row to be stored, it is possible to replace single values directly in `NEW` and return the modified `NEW`, or to build a complete new record/row to return.

I'd like to do the latter. I have a `SELECT` which is guaranteed to return a single row. How do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample:

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   sthg text NOT NULL,
   ip inet
);

CREATE FUNCTION sample_trig() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   SELECT 42, 'yes!', '127.0.0.1'::inet INTO NEW;
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER sample_trig
   BEFORE INSERT ON sample FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE sample_trig();

INSERT INTO sample VALUES (1, 'new', NULL);

TABLE sample;

 id | sthg |    ip     
----+------+-----------
 42 | yes! | 127.0.0.1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Ah! The key is that PL/pgSQL's [`SELECT INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) is different from the regular [`SELECT INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-selectinto.html).